# Google Analytics 4 (GA4) measurement protocol (debug view) not working

Tags: api, postman, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol, insomnia

I am trying to send an event to Google Analytics 4 with measurement protocol, via Insomnia.

I would like it to show up in GA4 debug view, so I've added the debug_mode parameter and changed the POST endpoint to /debug/mp/collect instead of /mp/collect. But it doesn't show up in debug view.

I have read similar questions about GA4 measurement protocol here on stackoverflow but can't find out why GA4 isn't receiving these POST requests. Do any of you know why it isn't working? See the images of my json body and header below.

Really need some help with this, thank you in advance.

[Image of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb9VF.jpg)

[Image of payload/object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Ieh.png)

Comment: did you find a solution by any chance ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I sent it the usual way so I could watch it in the GA4 realtime view.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. I'm sending events from a Laravel app, using the HTTP client. I can see them in realtime, but hitting the debug endpoint shows nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As it is said in the official documentation of [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/validating-events?client_type=gtag): "Events sent to the Validation Server will not show up in reports".

Thus, you need to change the endpoint of your call back to `/mp/collect` to be able to observe your events in the debug view.

Comment: Did you manage to view events sent through measurement protocol in debug view? If affirmative, what other steps besides switching the endpoint are needed?

Comment: @8ctopus In my case, adding `debug_mode: 1` was the only difference which did the thing.

This is how the event looks in common:

`{
  "timestamp_micros": 1689601586684000,
  "client_id": %ID,
  "user_properties": {
   ...properties
  },
  "events": [
    {
      "name": %EVENT_NAME%,
      "params": {
        "debug_mode": 1,
        "engagement_time_msec": 1,
        ...other params
      }
    }
  ]
}`